# denyAccessUnlessGranted in controller multiple roles

Tags: php, symfony, roles

I found this controller method that helps filtering access with a role name :

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_EDIT', $item, 'You cannot edit this item.');
```

Is it possible to use the same method with multiple roles. I tried something like this but it doesnt seems to work :

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(array('ROLE_EDIT', 'ROLE_WHATEVER'), $item, 'You cannot edit this item.');
```

Comment: what you want to express ? are both roles neccessary or one of both ?

Comment: i need both roles to be able access the action

Answer (score 10):

looking into the method shows how it works

```
protected function denyAccessUnlessGranted($attributes, $object = null, $message = 'Access Denied.')
{
    if (!$this->isGranted($attributes, $object)) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException($message);
    }
}
```

so you could easily adapt this to your case

in your controller sth. like:

```
if(!$this->isGranted('ROLE_EDIT', $item) && !$this->isGranted('ROLE_OTHER', $item)){
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('not allowed');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

denyAccessUnlessGranted accepts an array of Role Names, so

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(['ROLE_EDIT', 'ROLE_ADMIN'], $item, 'You cannot edit this item.');
```

so, you should be able to pass all your roles.

Craig

Comment: Note that this is deprecated since Symfony 4.4.

Comment: indeed, but valid when the answer given.

Comment: Sure, that's why I added "Note" so that anyone reading this today will know that this may not be valid anymore, depending on the used version of symfony.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Symfony 6.2 and my controllers extend a base controller that I use to add additional functionality. One of which is this method for checking user roles and it works with one or multiple.

```php
/**
 * Check user access permissions. If an array is supplied for $role, and $mustHaveAllRoles
 * is set to true, then the user must have all the roles. If $mustHaveAllRoles is false
 * then they must only have at least one of the listed roles.
 */
protected function checkAccess(array|string $role, bool $mustHaveAllRoles=true)
{    
    if (is_array($role)) {
        // We have several roles to check. By default they must have ALL the roles listed.
        $valid = true;
        foreach($role as $singleRole){
            if ($this->isGranted($singleRole)) {
                if (!$mustHaveAllRoles) {
                    return;
                }
            }else{
                $valid = false; // At least one role is not found for this user.
            }
        }
        if (!$valid) {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
        }
    }else{
        // Only one role was supplied. Check it.
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted($role);
    }
    
}
```

Call it from the top of a controller method like so:

```php
$this->checkAccess(['ROLE_USER_VERIFIED', 'ROLE_ADMIN']);
```